# Django installation on OSX

Tags: django, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

**OS : OS X 10.7.5**
I have **pyhton 3.3.2** installed under Apps folder and I use IDLE for python scripts.
I used below command to install Django.

```
pip install Django==1.5.2
```

After successful installation I see it installed under **~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/**

However when I use IDLE to test

```
import django
```

I get below error:

```
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import django
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

What am I missing ? This is the first time I am trying django installation.

As per suggestion, I installed virtualenv and tried

```
sudo virtualenv -p /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/ my_virtualenv
```

It failed with below trace:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.10.1', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 780, in main
    popen = subprocess.Popen([interpreter, file] + sys.argv[1:], env=env)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Seems like still its trying to install under 2.7 version.

Comment: You said you used Python3, but from the folder you can see it is installed in Python 2.7.

Comment: Installer picked the default path to ~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/. Is there a way to install it for Pyhton 3.3 which is installed under ~/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a conflict between python 2.7 and 3.3.2. You installed django for python 2.7 and certainly tried to used it with python 3.3.2.

The best way to avoid this kind of problem is to use virtualenv:

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Then:

```
$ virtualenv my_virtualenv
```

OR:

```
$ virtualenv -p <PATH TO PYTHON VERSION> my_virtualenv
```

Then:

```
$ source my_virtualenv/bin/activate
$ pip install Django==1.5.2
```

This will install the good version of django in your virtualenv. You need to check if the python 3 version is available with pip.

Thanks to virtualanv, you will be able to save/freeze and install your environement on another machine:

```
$ pip freeze > requirement.txt
$ pip install -r requirement.txt
```

Comment: Can't put a big comment here. I have updated my question after trying your suggestion with virtualenv.

Comment: Excellent instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that resolved my issue:

Removed Python 3.3 completely from machine.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3
sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 3.3"
cd /usr/local/bin; 
ls -l . | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3' | awk '{print $9}' | xargs rm
```

And then setup the environment using [guide](http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-install-django-on-mac-osx-lion-10.7/) to set Up Python and Install Django on Mac OS X.